# VueJS Props as Initial Value to Data

Tags: vue.js

I have the following VueJS component and am trying to set an initial value to a local data variable as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow).  The component code is as follows:

```
<template>
  <p>
    name: {{ name }} <br/>
    model: {{ model }}
  </p>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String
    }
  },

  data: function () {
    return {
      model: this.name
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The issue I'm facing is that when the component renders only the "name" is rendered while the "model" is empty.  I've been banging my head against this for a while now and feel like I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Are you sure that the `name` property is being supplied by the parent when this component is rendered? Maybe there's a delay (AJAX call?) before the parent sets a value? You could also define a default value for the `name` property and see if that default value is coped to the `model`

Comment: @StephenThomas yes the name property is supplied and is actually the only one that is rendered in the HTML.  The model is not being set.

If I added the "default" value to the `name` prop then that gets copied into the `model` data value as expected and rendered out correctly.

Comment: sounds like my original guess was correct. I bet if you set a breakpoint before the return, you'll find that the prop is `null`. Possible solution posted as an answer

Comment: Yeah your answer below was correct.  The issue was in fact in the parent.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the parent's use of this component, but based on the commentary, the most likely problem is that the parent is rendering the child with an initial `null` value for the `name` prop. That gets rendered in the child. The parent then updates its `name` prop which is reflected in the child. But because the child has already been created, its `model` data is already set (to `null`). You can fix this with a watcher.

```js
watch: {
    name() {
        this.model = this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue was in fact in the parent, there was a race condition between when the parent value was retrieved from the parent data source (a database) via AJAX and when the component props were passed in.