# How to properly update a prop used as an initial value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I'm wondering if I'm doing this the best way possible; I've built a component which accepts a list of items as a prop, but then I need to mutate that list internally in the component, so I followed the VueJs docs to provide the prop value as a data property's initial value, and then using the data property when I need to make any changes to the data.

```js
export default {
  props: {
    items: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => {
            return []
        }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
        itemList: this.items
    }
  }
}
```

I noticed however that this causes the `itemList` property to stick to the initial value, and won't update if the parent component provides a new `items` value to this component, this makes sense as the component was already rendered and thus it doesn't need to reevaluate all it's `data` properties; so to fix this I added a watcher to watch for any changes on `items`:

```js
watch: {
   items() {
        this.itemList = this.items;
    }
}
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434374/8437694) other question which had a similar issue and the accepted answer did just what I just did here; however I'd like to know if this is an expected and reliable method of fixing this issue or if there are other ways to do this?

Comment: Yes, this is done with a watcher. Instead of doing the same thing in `data`, a watcher can be made `immediate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *data* property uses the *prop* just for initialization. It won't react to *prop* value changes after that.

A *computed property* will, though. It's another way to do it, but since you're not actually doing any "computing" on the *prop* value, a *watcher* with a function that changes the *data* property seems more appropriate to me.

A regular *watcher* is **shallow**, though. Your suggestion shouldn't work if the parent element just mutated the array by adding or removing elements. It should only react to a **reassignment** of the array (I guess that's what your parent element did... replace the prop value entirely).

If you need the *watcher* to react to **mutations** to the prop as well, then you might want to create a [deep watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers):

```js
watch: {
   items: {
    handler(newValue) {
      this.itemList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newValue)); //deep array copy to prevent array mutations made by the child component from affecting the parent's array. Keep in mind this deep-copy technique using JSON has caveats.
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

But that can become quite expensive if your array prop grows big.

Also, it seems to me you intend for the state of your component (`$data.itemList`) to be changed both by the component itself and by its parent *at the same time*. This can get troublesome (racing conditions and whatnot), so be careful.

Comment: As @Estus Flask put it, you might as well add an `immediate: true` option to the watcher and remove the initialization from the component's *data* option.

Comment: Thank you! Could you add an example using the `immediate` option just to make sure I'm clear on that? How should I leave the data object then?

Comment: See example in [Eager Watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#eager-watchers).

This'll force your watcher to run its handler as soon as the component is created, which relieves $data.itemList from the need to initialize itself with the prop. So you'd better leave it like this:

`data() {
    return {
        itemList: [] //or null
    }
  }`

This way the whole logic stays within the watcher for items.

Comment: Yeah I changed it to that; also, could you elaborate on the last point you mentioned? about racing conditions?

Comment: For example: Maybe the parent updates or clears the itemList while the child is performing some other operation on it (and vice-versa) leading to undesired and unpredictable results.

The code as it is, is _not wrong_. It'll all depend on what your app needs and how you write it. You most probably will not have any issue at all.